# Polynomial Regression Plot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, stat, polynomial-math

Bit of a beginner in R, so I was adding polynomial regression models to a ‘Global Terrorism’ graph for degree 1, 2, 3, and 4 polynomials with different colors. I was working on the 1st degree and when I knit it and ran the program, it doesn't show up.

However the following error does pop up:

> Warning: Computation failed in `stat_function()`:
>   Elements must equal the number of rows or 1

Here's the code that I have so far:

```
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")
#library("ggrepel")
library("readr")
library("readxl") 

GTDbyYear <- read_csv("GTDbyYear.csv")


# exponential regression
exp_fit <- lm(log(attacks) ~ year, data = GTDbyYear)

# Polynomial regression Degree 1
polyRegOne_fit <- lm(attacks ~ poly(year,1), data = GTDbyYear )

# Polynomial regression Degree 2
polyRegTwo_fit <- lm(attacks ~ poly(year,2), data = GTDbyYear )

# Polynomial regression Degree 3
polyRegThree_fit <- lm(attacks ~ poly(year,3), data = GTDbyYear )

# Polynomial regression Degree 4
polyRegFour_fit <- lm(attacks ~ poly(year,4), data = GTDbyYear )

A <- exp(exp_fit$coefficients[1])
B <- exp(exp_fit$coefficients[2])

exp_function <- function(x){
  A*B^x
}
polyOne_function <- function(x){
  polyRegOne_fit
}


# graphing the data and adding model layer
GTDbyYear %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = attacks)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_function(fun = exp_function, color = "red") +
  stat_function(fun = polyOne_function, color = "blue") +
  labs(title = "Global Terrorism",
       subtitle = "Regression Models",
       caption = "Source: Global Terrorism Database") +
  theme_minimal()
```

---

Here's a screenshot what I got when I ran the code:

I was expecting a blue line for the 1st degree poly reg to show up, but it didn't appear.

[image]

Comment: Hi there ColdLogic121. Please provide some information on your data by editing your question and showing the result of `head(GTDbyYear, 20)`. Thanks and welcome to SO.

Comment: Hello, just showed the result of the code. I deleted the the summary and prediction lines as I realized it played no part in the problem at hand.

Comment: Furthmore, what did you mean by head(GTDbyYear, 20) ?

Comment: If you run `head(GTDbyYear, 20)` we get the first 20 lines of your dataset GTDbyYear.

Comment: Try `geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = attacks ~ poly(year,1), data = GTDbyYear, color = "blue")` instead of `stat_function(fun = polyOne_function, color = "blue")`. Your `polyOne_function` is not depending on `x`.

Comment: Try this one `polyOne_function <- function(x){
  predict(polyRegOne_fit, newdata = data.frame(year = x))
}`

Comment: Martin Gal, when I implmented you code, their was a null error, however substituting attacks for y and year for x worked for the second degree, however implmenting the same function (mind you changed in accordance to 3rd degree) resulted in an error similar to the one I got before. However, implmenting teunbrand's solution seem to work. So thank you guys!